# Error in Cloud9 for terraform - InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-cloud9

I am trying to create a role in Cloud9 with Terraform.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "firehose_role" {
  name = "firehose_test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Error:

```
failed creating IAM Role (firehose_test_role): InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid │ status code: 403, request id: 6ea2ca59-70ac-47b8-b83c-6547ad98aec1
```

And when I disable the "AWS managed temporary credentials", this is what I get:

```
Error: Invalid provider configuration
│ 
│ Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" requires explicit configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the provider's required arguments as described
│ in the provider documentation.
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
│ 
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│ 
│ Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, http response error StatusCode: 404, request to EC2 IMDS failed
│ 
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on <empty> line 0:
│   (source code not available)
```

So, what can I do here to make it work on Cloud9?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disallow AWS Managed Temporary Credentials

Go to *Cloud9 > Preferences > AWS Settings > AWS Managed Temporary Credentials* and turn it off

You will see a different error now (no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found).  Then you need either

> - Attaching an instance profile to the Amazon EC2 instance that connects
>   to our Cloud9 environment. You can refer to Create and Use an Instance
>   Profile to Manage Temporary Credentials

or

> - Store your permanent AWS access credentials in the environment. This
>   is similar to what we did earlier by running theaws configure command.
>   See Create and store permanent access credentials in an Environment.

Hope it helps.

More info:
https://aws-terraform-by-example.com/guide/9-introducing-cloud9.html#cloud9-setup